# Custom layer in tensorflow to output the running maximum of its inputs

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to create a custom layer in tensorflow to output the running maximum of its inputs. The layer has a memory variable and comparison function. I wrote the following

```
class ComputeMax(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

   def __init__(self):
       super(ComputeMax, self).__init__()

   def build(self, input_shape):
       self.maxval = tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.zeros((input_shape)),
                              trainable=False)

   def call(self, inputs):
       self.maxval.assign(tf.maximum(inputs, self.maxval))
       return self.maxval

my_sum = ComputeMax()
x = tf.ones((1,2))

y = my_sum(x)
print(y.numpy())  # [1, 1]

y = my_sum(x)
print(y.numpy())  # [1, 1]
```

It works as above. When I try it in a test model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(2)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))
model.add(ComputeMax())
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
```

I get the error on compile:

```
ValueError: Cannot convert a partially known TensorShape to a Tensor: (None, 1)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the layer needs to know the input neurons from the previous layer, which is the last value in `input_shape`. You are using `input_shape` as it is which is actually batch shape, leading to a layer of the shape of batch.

This implementation might help.

```
class ComputeMax(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

   def __init__(self):
       super(ComputeMax, self).__init__()

   def build(self, input_shape):
       self.maxval = tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.zeros((input_shape[-1])),
                              trainable=False)

   def call(self, inputs):
       self.maxval.assign(tf.maximum(inputs, self.maxval))
       return self.maxval
```

But probably it won't give you answers with numpy 1d array.

Comment: I tried your suggested change, and on compile, in the model above, it gives me the error, ValueError: Cannot assign to variable compute_max_29/Variable:0 due to variable shape (1,) and value shape (None, 1) are incompatible

Comment: Yeah, I know. The problem is with `call` method. But definitely, the build method is correct as you need to specify the input shape from the previous layer neurons.